# Pandas - Multiple iterations over same column based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a basic trading algo but my question has more to do with pandas.

See code:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import talib as ta


###########################################GETTING DATA###################################################

#Download Data
aapl = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start=datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 1), end=datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 8))



###############################################STRATEGY###################################################

#Initialize the `signals` DataFrame with the `signal` column
signals = pd.DataFrame(index=aapl.index)
signals['signal'] = 0.0

# Add price/Currently using Open Price
signals['Open'] = aapl.Open.values

# Create 10 MA moving average 
signals['10 MA'] = ta.SMA(aapl.Close.values,10)

# Create 25 EMA moving average
signals['25 EMA'] = ta.EMA(aapl.Close.values,25)

# Remove Nan rows
signals = signals.dropna()

# Create Buy Signal
signals['signal'] = np.where((signals['Close']>signals['25 EMA']),1.0,0)

#Create Sell Signal
#I want to hold the stock as long as its 1)above the price I paid for it and 2) if it ever gets above the 10 day moving average and later closes beneath it I want to sell


print (signals)
```

I've got a pandas dataframe (see below) and for each time the signal column = 1 (my buy signal) it means my buy criteria has been met, however, although this is just a snippet of the data and the signal appears to always be 1, it is not the case as we move further out in the data set.

Eventually, the buy criteria is no longer met and the signal column = 0, but there are instances where I would want to still hold the stock and identify that holding as a 1 in the signal column:

1) If it's above the price I entered the trade at

2) but If it has gone above the 10 day moving average since I bought it and as closed beneath it that would incite me to sell

All I'm trying to do is to figure out when to buy/hold/sell the stock and express that in the signal column so I can later analyze the returns.

If anyone has a better way of keeping track of these transactions, I'm all ears!

```
               signal   close       10 MA      25 EMA
Date
2010-10-06     1.0   41.369999   40.995285   39.372343
2010-10-07     1.0   41.477142   40.999571   39.521943
2010-10-08     1.0   41.672855   41.024571   39.713331
2010-10-11     1.0   42.105713   41.084571   39.904174
2010-10-12     1.0   42.201427   41.251428   40.115282
2010-10-13     1.0   42.885715   41.433857   40.327732
2010-10-14     1.0   43.098572   41.699000   40.547687
2010-10-15     1.0   43.919998   42.159285   40.887315
2010-10-18     1.0   45.495716   42.721571   41.236643
2010-10-19     1.0   43.342857   43.015142   41.465582
2010-10-20     1.0   44.142857   43.319999   41.688339
2010-10-21     1.0   44.622856   43.609999   41.882863
2010-10-22     1.0   44.152859   43.801428   42.039895
2010-10-25     1.0   44.155716   43.993999   42.199903
2010-10-26     1.0   43.838570   44.129856   42.338922
2010-10-27     1.0   43.950001   44.239714   42.464829
2010-10-28     1.0   43.992859   44.281571   42.552589
2010-10-29     1.0   43.461430   44.084999   42.586786
```

Comment: Everything's fine but a sample expected output will make it perfect to answer things properly :)

Comment: @Bharath The desired sample output is that same dataframe updated with more 1's in the Signal column. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: No idea what this question is asking. Is the signal column part of the original dataframe or is it generated from the data. What is the original day? What do you mean by iterating over the rows? You need to provide the output dataframe.

Comment: @TedPetrou The original dataframe consists of the above dataframe exlcuding the signal column which I got from yahoo finance. I later added the "signal" column as well as the "1" 's where the trading strategy gives me a "buy signal". The problem I'm having is that I need to keep track of when the strategy should sell the particular stock. By adding more 1's to the dataframe above I'll be able to distinguish between when I'm holding the stock or not in order to track my gains/losses. The original day is the first one in the dataframe.

Comment: @TedPetrou What I mean by iterating over rows is going through the rows 1 by 1 to identify those that currently have "1" in the "Signal" column. From each "buying" point, I want to see until when I will hold the stock (hold = 1, Not Holding = 0)

Comment: How would adding more 1's in the same column help you? It will only be more confusing since you won't be able to differentiate the original 1's from the added 1's.

Comment: @TedPetrou I will be able to differentiate the original from the added 1's by looking at the previous # (if its 0 then its the original = buy, if its 1 its been added = hold). This will really help me as I'll then be able to see how this strategy performed over time and analyze returns.

Comment: @TedPetrou If you have another way of keeping track of when to buy/sell/hold, I am very open to it!

Comment: As another person has said. You need to put the final dataframe that you want to see. I can't read your mind and your explanations are not very clear.

Comment: @TedPetrou Hi Ted, thanks for your patience. I've updated the question. I hope this is more clear.